# Parse xsd with values [python]

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I'm trying to examine and extract some data from an xml file using python. I'm doing this by parsing with etree then looping through the elements:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
    root = etree.fromstring(xml_string) 

for element in root.iter():
    print("%s , %s , %s" % (element.tag, element.attrib, element.text))
```

This works fine for some test data, but the actual xml files that I'm working with seem to contain xsd tags along with the data. Below is an example

```
<wdtf:observationMember>
  <wdtf:TimeSeriesObservation gml:id="ts1">
    <gml:description>Reading using DTW (Depth To Water) from TOC</gml:description>
    <gml:name codeSpace="http://www.bom.gov.au/std/water/xml/wio0.2/feature/TimeSeriesObservation/w00066/12/A/GroundWaterLevel/">1</gml:name>
    <om:procedure xlink:href="#gwTOC12" />
    <om:observedProperty xlink:href="http://www.bom.gov.au/std/water/xml/wio0.2/property//bom/GroundWaterLevel_m" />
    <om:featureOfInterest xlink:href="http://www.bom.gov.au/std/water/xml/wio0.2/feature/BorePipeSamplingInterval/w00066/12" />
    <wdtf:metadata>
      <wdtf:TimeSeriesObservationMetadata>
        <wdtf:regulationProperty>Reg200806.s3.2a</wdtf:regulationProperty>
        <wdtf:status>validated</wdtf:status>
      </wdtf:TimeSeriesObservationMetadata>
    </wdtf:metadata>
    <wdtf:result>
      <wdtf:TimeSeries>
        <wdtf:defaultInterpolationType>InstVal</wdtf:defaultInterpolationType>
        <wdtf:defaultUnitsOfMeasure>m</wdtf:defaultUnitsOfMeasure>
        <wdtf:defaultQuality>quality-A</wdtf:defaultQuality>
        <wdtf:timeValuePair time="1915-12-09T12:00:00+10:00">51.82</wdtf:timeValuePair>
        <wdtf:timeValuePair time="1917-12-18T12:00:00+10:00">41.38</wdtf:timeValuePair>
        <wdtf:timeValuePair time="1924-05-23T12:00:00+10:00">21.95</wdtf:timeValuePair>
        <wdtf:timeValuePair time="1988-02-02T12:00:00+10:00">7.56</wdtf:timeValuePair>
      </wdtf:TimeSeries>
    </wdtf:result>
  </wdtf:TimeSeriesObservation>
</wdtf:observationMember>
```

Useing this xml in the code above causes etree to return an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xml_test2.py", line 38, in <module>
root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
File "<string>", line 124, in XML
ParseError: unbound prefix: line 1, column 4
```

Is there a different parser I should be using? Or can I remove the xsc tags some how?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the actual error message.

Comment: Hi Mike the erroro I get is:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_test2.py", line 38, in <module>
    root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 124, in XML
  ParseError: unbound prefix: line 1, column 4

Comment: Are you loading the XML from a file? If you are you should use `root = etree.parse("myfile.xsd").getroot()"` instead of `root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)`.

Comment: ok will do, thanks mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your post, your parser is namespace aware and is complaining that XML namespace aliases are not resolved. Assuming that `<wdtf:observationMember>` is your topmost element, then you have to have the following at least:

```
<wdtf:observationMember xmlns:wdtf="some-uri">
```

The same applies for all other prefixes, such as `gml`, `om`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Petru, think I have it sorted out now. I was clipping the observation member out of a much larger block of xml and missed the name space